# Command is giving the bot role

Tags: discord, discord.js

I'm trying to make a command that gives a user a role. It was working before, but not it just gives the bot a role.

```
module.exports = {
  name: "addevent",
  description: "Add the event ping role to a user",

  async run(client, message, args) {

    const { member } = message;

    if (message.member.roles.cache.has('793222158981529621')) {
      const { member } = message;
      message.channel.send(`${member} You already have this role.`)
    }

    if (message.channel.id !== '793224633759432755') return;    

    member.roles.add('793222158981529621')

    message.channel.send(`${member} Added the event ping role.`)
  }
}
```

This is also happening to my level command that's supposed to check a user's level. It checks the bot's level, not the user's.

Answer (score 1):

```js
    let role = message.guild.roles.cache.find(r => r.name === "Role Name Here");

    if (message.channel.id !== 'Channel ID Here') return;

    if (message.member.roles.cache.has(role.id)) {
      return message.channel.send(`${message.member} You already have this role.`)
    }

    message.member.roles.add(role);
    message.channel.send(`${message.member} Added the event ping role.`);
```

My example has a variable called `role` which finds the role by its name, so you have to provide the name of the role there. Your if-statement with the `message.channel.id` was understandable and is a nice way to get the role in only one channel. The second if-statement just asks if a user already has that role (dont forget: in `.has()` you have to provide an ID, in this case it is easily done with `role.id`). Anyways if the user has that role it will send a message and return. Otherwise it will add the role to the user and also send a message.

Comment: > I don't know why you wanted member to be the message?


    `const { member } = message;` is using Node.Js Deconstructing. It is the same as `const member = message.member;`

Otherwise good answer.

Comment: Oh that's good to know thank you, I removed that from my answer now.

Comment: I tried that, and it's still giving the bot the role.

Comment: I ended up fixing the error, apparently it was because of one of the packages I installed.